# uploading using python request to forum

Tags: python, python-requests, upload

I am trying to upload to a file but having issues. The site seems to be using XenForo judging by its appearance.

Even when doing the upload via a browser and preventing it using burp suite and running it as a curl command i get a 500 server error.

On other sites i can do a simple post with the file but on this site capturing the file upload packet I can see the data packet contains things like file size of the file, parts etc..

From what i can gather from monitoring the upload with burp site is these are the steps.

```
1. go to upload page. (When you go to create a forum post each on seems to have a unique id and hash for the file attached to it.)
2. get the nodeid and hash
3. upload file by posting it to endpoint with the nodeid and hash from previous step
4. add rest of post 
5. submit the post with the file and message in the post.
submit
```

Here is a sample of the post request when the file is being uploaded using a browser. Note this fails and gives 500 error.

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'xf_csrf': 'xxx',
    'userinit': 'xxx',
    'xf_user': 'xxx',
    'xf_session': 'xxx',
    'xf_sam_ad_views': 'xxx',
}

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.redacted.xxxx',
    # 'Content-Length': '37041',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120"',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"macOS"',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.6099.71 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarydF2mkP3SuKAZcAbY',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Origin': 'www.redacted.xxxx',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://www.redacted.xxxx/index.php?forums/uploading-your-files-here.132/post-thread',
    # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'Priority': 'u=1, i',
    # 'Cookie': 'xf_csrf=eLCr678lwNq2iMmn; userinit=95ddb5df7463d0efb98021f9371989c9; xf_user=109501%2CYNCgLy7T_ABAHuS8KFzwhZgGZI5MgXTpSGquUidE; xf_session=BaUI9uwtS72mSmc_xWpl1BroSBMib7OT; xf_sam_ad_views=%7B%221%22%3A1705583226%7D',
}

data = '------WebKitFormBoundarydF2mkP3SuKAZcAbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="_xfToken"\r\n\r\n1705596291,78532c7a685caedfcab17cd6d406c086\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydF2mkP3SuKAZcAbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="_xfResponseType"\r\n\r\njson\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydF2mkP3SuKAZcAbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="_xfWithData"\r\n\r\n1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydF2mkP3SuKAZcAbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="flowChunkNumber"\r\n\r\n1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydF2mkP3SuKAZcAbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="flowChunkSize"\r\n\r\n4294967296\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydF2mkP3SuKAZcAbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="flowCurrentChunkSize"\r\n\r\n35356\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydF2mkP3SuKAZcAbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="flowTotalSize"\r\n\r\n35356\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydF2mkP3SuKAZcAbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="flowIdentifier"\r\n\r\n35356-NameOfTheFile.tx\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydF2mkP3SuKAZcAbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="flowFilename"\r\n\r\nName of the file.txt\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydF2mkP3SuKAZcAbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="flowRelativePath"\r\n\r\nName of the file.txt\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydF2mkP3SuKAZcAbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="flowTotalChunks"\r\n\r\n1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydF2mkP3SuKAZcAbY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="Name of the file.txt"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\nd8:CONTENTS OF THE FILE\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydF2mkP3SuKAZcAbY--\r\n'.encode()

response = requests.post(
    'https://www.redacted.xxxx/index.php?attachments/upload&type=post&context[node_id]=166&hash=3823b19b536abcf1dc52c6a7effbb232',
    cookies=cookies,
    headers=headers,
    data=data,
    verify=False,
)
```

**Here is my code**
I can go to the forum thread post page and get the nodeid and hash without issue but the problem is when i try to post the file. Even when i run the curl command of the browser capture it fails with 400 error. I assume things like the flowTotalSize, totalchunksize etc.. are needed but is there a way i can just pass the file or is there a easier way to do this.

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'xf_csrf': 'xx',
    'userinit': 'xx',
    'xf_user': 'xx',
    'xf_session': 'xx',
    'xf_sam_ad_views': 'xx',
}

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.xx.xx',
    # 'Content-Length': '37041',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120"',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"macOS"',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.6099.71 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyCixpRISB1vZhlQr',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Origin': 'https://www.xx.xx',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://www.redacted.xxxx/index.php?forums/uploading-your-files-here.132/post-thread',
    # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'Priority': 'u=1, i',
    # 'Cookie': 'xf_csrf=eLCr678lwNq2iMmn; userinit=95ddb5df7463d0efb98021f9371989c9; xf_user=109501%2CYNCgLy7T_ABAHuS8KFzwhZgGZI5MgXTpSGquUidE; xf_session=BaUI9uwtS72mSmc_xWpl1BroSBMib7OT; xf_sam_ad_views=%7B%221%22%3A1705583226%7D',
}


s = requests.Session()

response = s.get('https://www.redacted.xxxx/index.php?forums/uploading-your-files-here.132/post-thread', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, verify=False)
print(response.status_code)

nodeid = response.text.split("node_id]=",1)[1][:3]
hash = response.text.split("hash=",1)[1][:32]

print(nodeid, hash)

with open(f"Name of the file.txt", 'rb') as f:
    tfile = f.read()
    f.close()

files = {
    'filename': (f"Name of the file.txt", tfile)
}

data = {
    # 'flowCurrentChunkSize' :
    # 'flowTotalSize' :
    # 'flowIdentifier' :
    'flowFilename' : 'Name of the file.txt',
    'flowRelativePath' : 'Name of the file.txt',
    'upload' :  files
}

response = s.post(f'https://www.redacted.xxxx/index.php?attachments/upload&type=post&context[node_id]={nodeid}&hash={hash}', cookies=cookies, data=data, headers=headers, verify=False)

print(response.status_code)
```

output

```
200
132 3823b19b536abcf1dc52c6a7effbb222
400
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.